# error: Unable to append to ./logs/HEAD: Permission denied

Tags: git, gitlab

I've been pushing code to gitlab from my local computer. It's been working great but all of the sudden I've been getting this error:

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 324 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: Unable to append to ./logs/HEAD: Permission denied
To git@example.com:1/53.git
   2924375..78b7f43  master -> master
```

Never seen it (error: Unable to append to ./logs/HEAD: Permission denied) before but I'm not seeing my new commits on my gitlab server. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: So, have you checked the permissions? If linux tells you there is no permissions for some operation it's a high chance that's true.

Comment: Also, check our disk usage.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am facing the same problem. And these suggestions (did you check permissions? check disk usage?) are ridiculous. Those things are fine.

Comment: @bumpkin did you find the solution? Stuck in same problem.

Comment: I have this problem pushing to a non-GitLab bare repo on Ubuntu 20.04, and permissions are likely an issue.  For example, my `logs/HEAD` file has `-rw-r--r--` permissions, and I push as a different user than the owner, which explains why I can't write to the file.  A good first step in answering this question, then, is to establish what ownership and permissions Git expects `logs/HEAD` to have.  One answer below says without citation that it should be owned by the 'git' user, but I don't believe that's strictly true.

Comment: Of course, if this is a permissions issue on the receiving end, that would be GitLab's server, so GitLab would probably need to fix it.  I don't know, I've never used GitLab.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of the file '/53.git/logs/HEAD' on server 'example.com:1'. It must belong to user 'git'.

Comment: This answer can be improved with a reference to documentation, especially since I suspect it isn't true.  For instance, I'm able to push to a remote Git repo on a server that doesn't even have a 'git' user.